# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing

I am not able to figure out why this error is coming 

 Here is full error

```
 Error:Execution failed for task          
 ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest'.
 > java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper       
  '-keep' options?
```

My gradle android project was not having "androidTest" so I created manually and test folder here is screenshot of folder structure
  [image]

Comment: Did you added `multiDexEnabled true ` in your build.gradle file?

Comment: No I just removed testInstrumentationRunner="android.support....." from file and restarted It starts working.

Comment: Add please Solution section in your post. Maybe someone would look for answer for this question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider it as perfect answer but this is what i did.
I removed **testInstrumentationRunner="android.support.test.runner....."** from build.gradle file and restarted 
It starts working :)
It is just for information

Comment: First useful answer. If someone have a better solution - give it, but don't give minus.